# cannot load such file -- Qt4

Tags: ruby, qt4

I want to start work with Ruby+Qt4. I've downloaded

```
$yum list qt* | less

Installed Packages
QtDMM.x86_64                         0.8.12-4.fc17          @fedora             
qt.i686                              1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt.x86_64                            1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-assistant.x86_64                  1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-creator.x86_64                    2.4.1-2.fc17           @fedora             
qt-demos.x86_64                      1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-devel.x86_64                      1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-doc.noarch                        1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-examples.x86_64                   1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-mobility.i686                     1.2.0-10.20110922.fc17 @fedora             
qt-mobility.x86_64                   1.2.0-10.20110922.fc17 @fedora             
qt-settings.noarch                   4.8-22.fc17            @updates            
qt-x11.i686                          1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt-x11.x86_64                        1:4.8.4-1.fc17         @updates            
qt3.x86_64                           3.3.8b-41.fc17         @fedora             
qt4-theme-quarticurve.x86_64         0.0-0.17.beta8.fc17    @fedora             
qtscriptbindings.x86_64              0.2.0-3.fc17           @updates            
qtsoap.x86_64                        2.7-3.fc17             @fedora             
qtwebkit.i686                        2.2.2-1.fc17           @updates            
qtwebkit.x86_64                      2.2.2-1.fc17           @updates            
qtwebkit-devel.x86_64                2.2.2-1.fc17           @updates
```

then I've created new qt project and converted it into ruby code

```
$rbuic4 -x example.ui -o example.rb
```

then I've tried to compile `example.rb`
`$ruby example.rb` 
and the following error appeared:

```
/home/n/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- Qt4 (LoadError)
    from /home/n/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from example.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The package you were looking for is `ruby-qt`. `$yum list qt* | less` cannot find `ruby-qt`. Anyway, all ruby-qt binary packages are outdated. Do `sudo gem install qtbindings` as Karl suggested. It will compile from a maintained source repository of ruby-qt. The qtbindings home page is at https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/ .

Answer (score 0):

try `gem install qtbindings`

and in example.rb `require 'Qt'`